# Violation of Bell-like inequalities with spatial Boltzmann path ensemble: Ising model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, path-integral, ising-model, bells-inequality

Quantum mechanics is equivalent with [Feynman path ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation), which after Wick rotation becomes Boltzmann path ensemble, which can be normalized into stochastic process as maximal entropy random walk [(MERW)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_Entropy_Random_Walk).

But Boltzmann path ensemble has also spatial realization: 1D [Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model) and its generalizations: Boltzmann distribution among spatial sequences of spins or some more complicated objects.

For $E_{uv}$ energy of interaction between $u$ and $v$ neighboring spins or something more general, define $M_{uv} = \exp(-\beta E_{uv})$ as transition matrix and find its dominant eigenvalue/vector: $M \psi = \lambda \psi$ for maximal $|\lambda|$. Now it is easy to find (e.g. [derived here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.13300)) that probability distribution of one and two neighboring values inside such sequence are:

$$Pr(u) = (\psi_u)^2\qquad\qquad Pr(u,v) = \psi_u \frac{M_{uv}}{\lambda} \psi_v$$

The former resembles QM [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule), the latter [TSVF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-state_vector_formalism) – the two ending $\psi$ come from propagators from both infinities as $M^p \approx \lambda^p \psi \psi^T$ for unique dominant eigenvalue thanks to Frobenius-Perron theorem. We nicely see this Born rule coming from symmetry here: spatial in Ising, time in MERW.

Having Ising-like models as spatial realization of Boltzmann path integrals getting Born rule from symmetry, maybe we could construct Bell violation example with it?

Here is MERW construction ([page 9 here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.2724)) for violation of Mermin’s **Pr(A=B) + Pr(A=C) + Pr(B=C) >= 1** inequality for 3 binary variables ABC, intuitively “tossing 3 coins, at least 2 are equal” (e.g. [here is QM violation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.5214)):

[image]

From Ising perspective, we need 1D lattice of 3 spins with constraints – allowing neighbors only accordingly to blue edges in above diagram, or some other e.g. just forbidding |000> and |111>.

Measurement of AB spins is defect in this lattice as above – fixing only the measured values. Assuming uniform probability distribution among all possible sequences, the red boxes have correspondingly 1/10, 4/10, 4/10, 1/10 probabilities – leading to Pr(A=B) + Pr(A=C) + Pr(B=C) = 0.6 violation.

Could this kind of spin lattice construction be realized?

What types of constraints/interaction in spin lattices can be realized?

While Ising-like models provide spatial realization of Boltzmann path integrals, is there spatial realization of Feynman path integrals?

---

Update: sketch of derivation of the formulas above of probabilities inside Ising's Boltzmann sequence ensemble:

[image]

Comment: Another paper about Bell violation with Ising model: https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.123.170604

Comment: If we can violate Bell-like inequalities with Ising, maybe we could realize quantum-like computers this way? While such Wick-rotated quantum gates seem computationally a bit weaker, such spatial realization allows to fix amplitudes from both directions: left and right, what seems to allow to quickly solve NP-complete problems from Boltzmann sequence ensemble - end of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.13300

Comment: Lecture about MERW and such view on Ising model: https://youtu.be/k8T1jVBHWrM